# The difference between computed and watch in Vue2.0

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, frontend

When we discuss the difference between computed and watch in Vue2.0, we always say that there are two main differences

1. Do not perform asynchronous operations in `computed`
2. High-load calculations should executed in `watch`.

However, after reading the Vue2.0 source code, I have doubts about these two points.

For the first point, **Do not perform asynchronous operations in `computed`**.
I know this code is not right

```js
computed: {
  myComputed: async function() {
    let returnVal = await this.asyncRequestMethod(this.attributeA) // An async request
    return returnVal
  },
  myComputed2: function() {
    let returnVal = this.asyncRequestMethod(this.attributeA) // An async request
    return returnVal
  }
}
```

However, I think it is ok if my code is like this

```js
computed:{
  myComputed: function() {
    this.attributeB = this.asyncRequestMethod(this.attributeA) // An async request
    return this.attributeA * 2
  }
}
```

By using this code, every time `attributeA` change, I will return a new `myComputed`, at the same time, I will send a request to get a new value for `attributeB`. And it seems everything works smoothly.

For the second point, **High-load calculations should executed in watch.**

I think the difference is that if we have a computationally intensive task, executing it in `computed` will cause this task to happen in the macrotask queue.
And if it is executed in `watch`, it will cause this task to be executed in the microtask of the current event loop.

However, after my attempts, if our calculation task is very very complicated, whether it is placed in `computed` or `watch`, it will cause the page to freeze. So it's not clear to me why complex tasks are put in the microtask queue, does it help page performance?

We know the attributes defined both in `computed` and `watch` will create a `Watcher` object.

Regarding the ***first question***, I think that if I put an asynchronous request into `computed` (as I did in the second code snippet above), although this will not cause system errors, this is not a recommended practice.
Since this violates the semantics of `computed`, this is more of a listener or a watcher. At the same time, if our page does not request this computed attribute, then our asynchronous request will not be triggered.

Regarding the ***second question***, I think that if complex tasks are executed in the macro task queue, this will block other tasks in the macro task. May have an impact on performance. But I'm not sure why putting in the microtask queue is a better choice.

As a summary, I think either don't use asynchronous requests in computed, or don't perform complex calculations in computed. Compared with ***"not allowed"***, it is actually ***"not recommended"***.

Hope someone can answer my question or point out my mistake. Thanks!

Comment: `this.attributeB` will be a promise, not a value returned by the async method.

Comment: "I think the difference is that" - no, the difference is that you shouldn't perform side effects in a computed. You're just misusing it. It's unclear why you put emphasis on "microtask" thing. This doesn't matter if you have a blocking operation, it will block main thread. This isn't specific to Vue, these are the fundamentals of JS. The question lacks the specific code that could be discussed.